# WebLogic 12 web service error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: eclipse, web-services, junit, wsdl, weblogic12c

I can call a web service deployed on WebLogic 12c via SOAPUI and it works fine. The WSDL comes up fine in a browser.
But when I call it from JUnit in Eclipse, this is the error it throws upon attempting to parse the WSDL: 
[Fatal Error] The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
My eclipse, and the JUnit tests are using Java 1.6. I took the WSDL can built the client using maven. But it only fails upon calling the web service. Could this be an encoding issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you express your tests as a single root testsuite with multiple testcases beneath the root testsuite?

The xml specification allows single root element only, that is why the parser complains about not well-formed markup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Junit test itself is not in XML. It's a java class which extends TestCase. One thing that I discovered just a minute ago is that if I include the weblogic.jar (10.3) in the eclipse Junit client project path, the web service call works. If I remove that, and include the weblogic.jar from the 12c server/lib, I get the XML error. So I guess using the 10.3 weblogic.jar is a workaround until we convert everything to java 8. Thanks again.